# Javascript Cross Subdomain XMLHTTPRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain, jsonp, cors

I'm researching a solution for a bandwidth intensive project I am working on.  It involves doing POST and GET requests client side to different servers at different locations.   All the servers are mine.

The reasoning behind this design is to prevent a single server/location from becoming too busy and slowing down due to the high bandwidth needs of the project.  It mainly involves uploading and downloading large files.

With current technologies I would need to proxy these GET and POST requests server side due to the cross-site scripting restrictions.  That is the very thing I want to avoid, since it would still utilize bandwidth at a single point.

I've been reading about emerging technologies such as CORS and JSON-P that appear to allow this function.  I don't mind the solution being HTML5 only.  I do however want to be able to use JQuery.

Is it correct to assume that these new technologies will allow the function I want?
Where is the best place to start researching these two technologies?
Which one is recommended?

Comment: You do have access to the server right? If so, you could look into removing these cross-site restrictions on the server-side

Comment: @Joeytje50 they are browser security restrictions

Comment: If you change `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` it won't have the same browser restrictions anymore.

Answer (score 3):

You want CORS.  JQuery will play fine with that.  Old browsers, most notably IE<10 will not play nicely but if you can ignore those, go with CORS.